# Rsync does nothing?

Tags: rsync

I have only been experimenting with Rsync for a few minutes and find myself slightly lost.  I ran the command

```
rsync -avz -e "ssh -p portNo" /path/to/local/folder user@remoteip:/path/to/remote/folder
```

Rsync got back to me with a file listing but nothing changed on the remote folder. What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe

```
rsync -auvze ssh /local/path/ user@host:port/remote/path/
```

Anyways, this sort of question is better to be posted on http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the quotes are messed up; make them explicit with single quotes, including port number (12345 for example)

```
rsync -azu -e 'ssh -p 12345' /path/to/local/folder user@remoteip:/path/to/remote/folder
```